# Bus error (core dumped) due to Permission changes

Tags: command-line, permissions, linux-kernel, sudo, chmod

The following error occurs due to change in permission in a jupyter environment: It occurs irrespective of execution of a python script or other execution operation with userX.

```
 Bus error (core dumped)
```

Note: **While working with root it works fine**.

I remember changing permissions, mainly `chmod 755 /` and also `chmod -R 755 /home/userX` with root access.

I guess changing or revoking the file permission should work. But I am unable to figure out. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was mainly with the **memory space** somehow, and had to free up space within the user home path and everything seemed to be normal again.

Also to note never to use `chmod 777 /` in the root directory. This might lead to some changes especially when your using server environment.