# How to solve Bus error (core dumped) in python?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I was running python script on `EC2` instance. Due to out of storage, I had to extend the storage by `4GB`. After I extended the storage of the instance. I try to run the python script, at that time I'm encountering this error.

Any thoughts or suggestions to sort this out?

Comment: Does this answer your question : [Bus error (core dumped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626598/bus-error-core-dumped-due-to-permission-changes)

Comment: Thank you for ur suggestion. But that is not a solution I guess. I had a look at it already

Answer (score 2):

When you get error like Bus error or segmentation fault. Please,check below steps

1. Whether Memory of instance is full or not
2. Whether folder/code have enough permissions to run or not.

If none of above issues are occured then try running below commands in terminal
to identify from where this exact issue is coming from, in the code.

```
gdb python
(gdb) run /path/to/script.py
## wait for segfault ##
(gdb) backtrace
## stack trace of the c code
```

Above commands solved my problem. Hope, this helps when someone get similar issues.

Comment: Checkout this blog https://blog.opstree.com/2019/04/02/resolving-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-ubuntu/ too. Might help in solving this issue.